# TryGetValue in condition in dictionary

Tags: c#

I  need to check weather any value present in dictionary or not using TryGetValue.
This is my code.

```
return $"{context.Headers["routingkey"]}_Killswitch_Api";
```

Here - `context.Headers` is dictionary.

This what I have tried :-

```
string keyvalue = string.Empty;
if (context.Headers.TryGetValue("routingkey",out keyvalue))
{
    return $"{keyvalue}_Killswitch_Api";
}
else
{
    return "_Killswitch_Api";
}
```

Please let me know what I have tried is correct approach or not ? Please suggest me

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Are you running into a specific error or problem?

Comment: seems alright to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted solution looks fine to me. As a style suggestion, you can just do this because the output value is initialized to null if the value isn't found, which string interpolates to an empty string:

```cs
string keyvalue;
context.Headers.TryGetValue("routingkey", out keyvalue);
return $"{keyvalue}_Killswitch_Api";
```

See the docs for [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alyssa for your response

Comment: @Kannan You're welcome! Please note the little checkmark ✓ for answers that satisfy the question :-)

Comment: Actually it's defaulted to `null` and when you use a `null` in string interpolation it results in an empty string.  Also you could inline the declaration like this `context.Headers.TryGetValue("routingkey", out var keyvalue);`

Comment: @juharr: Good catch. I edited my answer to no longer be incorrect. Good to have extra options re: inline declaration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are doing is valid.

It is unnecessary to initialize `keyvalue` with a `string.Empty` if you are not using it further in the program.

If you want, you could also do:

```
string keyvalue; 
if (!context.Headers.TryGetValue("routingkey", out keyvalue))
{
    keyvalue = string.Empty;
}

return $"{keyvalue}_Killswitch_Api";
```

Which would essentially accomplish the same thing.

Comment: This is what I am looking